# Populate select element options according to another select value - Angular

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I have 2 consecutive select elements and i want the second one to be dependent on the selected vaulue of the first one.

```
<select ng-model="selectedSeason" ng-options="item.number for item in Season"></select>

<select  ng-model="selectedEpisode" ng-options="item.episodeOrder for item in selectedSeason" | range:item.episodeOrder> </select>
```

So far i managed to get the first select to populate correctly but the second one is showing values of undefined after selecting a value in the first element. changing "item.episodeOrder for item" in the second select to "item for item" inserts all choosen Season JSON values according to the selected value of the first select but i still can't manage to get it right.

Is this because the second select considers item of "selectedSeason" as item.number which doesn't contain the field "episodeOrder" ?

A season JSON example looks like this:

```
{
"id": 307,
"number": 1,
"episodeOrder": 10
}
```

In addition i tried to have the second select element insert the options counting from 0 and up to "episodeOrder" value by using this filter (which didn't really work):

```
list.filter('range', function() {
return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);

    for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
        input.push(i);
    }

    return input;
};
});
```

Thanks

Comment: you will have to do it as an object with the episodeOrder field or you can do item in selectedSeason without the for

Comment: removing the for didn't work as this was a syntax error compared to expected syntax of ng-options

Answer (score 1):

You are referring loop parameter of first tag which is not accessible from second loop. So you should refer ng-model of first tag

instead of

```
<select  ng-model="selectedEpisode" ng-options="item.episodeOrder for item in selectedSeason" | range:item.episodeOrder> </select>
```

try

```
<select  ng-model="selectedEpisode" ng-options="item.episodeOrder for item in selectedSeason" | range: selectedSeason.episodeOrder> </select>
```

Comment: unfortunately this still gives the undefined value